# Reading in all but the last character of this input string?

Tags: c++

Unfortunately this is only reading in vertexes A - F but not G. Basically in this loop `while(input.find(' ', pos1) != string::npos)` its terminating one character earlier than I want it to, but I'm not sure what to change. I created this code simply to read in the input via redirection and create a map of vertexes and a vector of characters for a graph. It's not very elegant so if you want to suggest a more effective way of reading in the input then that's good too. Thanks!

```
void MSTapp::processFile()
{
int pos1;
int pos2;
map<char, Vertex*> adjacencyList;
vector<char> listOrder;
string input;
bool test = false;
while (getline(cin, input)) {
    pos1 = pos2 = 0;
    if(std::string::npos != input.find_first_of("0123456789"))
    {

        char source = input[0];
        char destination = input[2];
        stringstream ss(input.substr(4));       
        int weight;
        ss >> weight;
        Edge newEdge(destination, weight);
        adjacencyList[source]->addEdge(destination, newEdge);
        Edge roadBack(source, weight);
        adjacencyList[destination]->addEdge(source, roadBack);
    }
    else
    {
        while(input.find(' ', pos1) != string::npos)
        {
            pos2 = input.find(' ', pos1);
            char vertex = input[pos1];
            listOrder.push_back(vertex);
            Vertex* newVertex = new Vertex(vertex);
            adjacencyList.insert(make_pair(vertex, newVertex));
            pos1 = pos2 + 1;
        };
    };
};
Graph graph(listOrder, adjacencyList);
prim(graph, adjacencyList[listOrder[0]]);
}
```

Input

```
A B C D E F G
A B 3
A E 4
B C 7 
B E 6
B F 5
C D 9
C F 8
D F 9
D G 4
E F 6
F G 8
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the iteration that `while(input.find(' ', pos1) != string::npos)` fails to find a space character, `input[pos1]` points to the last non-space character.

That's because spaces are between the characters, not after them.  This is what is sometimes called a "fencepost error".  It comes from a logic puzzle:  "Suppose you want to put a fence along a 10m stretch, with one fencepost every 1m.  How many fenceposts do you need?" 10 might seem the obvious answer, but 11 is the better answer, as 10 gaps need 11 fenceposts.  Same idea here.

A more obvious way to write the logic would be to search for the characters, not the spaces between them.  For example:

```
    while( (pos2 = input.find_first_of("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ", pos1)) != string::npos)
    {
        char vertex = input[pos2];
        listOrder.push_back(vertex);
        Vertex* newVertex = new Vertex(vertex);
        adjacencyList.insert(make_pair(vertex, newVertex));
        pos1 = pos2 + 1;
    }
```

Note that you will have to change the declaration for `pos1` and `pos2` to `std::string::size_type pos1, pos2;`.  And actually, you don't need two separate `pos` variables:

```
    std::string::size_type pos = 0;

    while( (pos = input.find_first_of("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ", pos)) != string::npos)
    {
        char vertex = input[pos];
        listOrder.push_back(vertex);
        Vertex* newVertex = new Vertex(vertex);
        adjacencyList.insert(make_pair(vertex, newVertex));
        ++pos;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for providing a solution that works with my existing code, but I have a feeling I'd get better practice by solving this using a stringstream. I'm going to attempt that, but if you have a suggested solution with a stringstream that would be awesome to help me learn!

Comment: On second thought why change something that is already working... This is pretty semantic code and sometimes that is convenient in itself

Comment: Awesome fix. It is now working and it concludes a couple of days of working on prim's algorithm to create a minimum spanning tree. There's nothing like the good feeling that comes from working compiled code :)